# Delete identical files saved as output in a log

Tags: sed, rm

I have three files in two folders. The files are named, `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` were located in `A` and `B` folders. I have used an app *Full File Mini Comparer* which compares the folder and saves to log to the `A` folder.

The log has some text as follows:

```
Different: A=/sdcard/A/a.txt B=/sdcard/B/a.txt
Same: A=/sdcard/A/b.txt B=/sdcard/B/b.txt
Different: A=/sdcard/A/c.txt B=/sdcard/B/c.txt
```

How can I use `sed` and `rm` or perhaps some other command to remove/delete the "Same" files permanently.

Answer (score 9):

You have

```
$ tree
.
|-- A
|   |-- a.txt
|   |-- b.txt
|   `-- c.txt
`-- B
    |-- a.txt
    |-- b.txt
    `-- c.txt

2 directories, 6 files
```

Using `fdupes`:

```
$ fdupes -1 A B
A/b.txt B/b.txt
```

`fdupes` detects duplicates based on file contents.  The `-1` flag makes it output the filenames of each set of duplicates on a single line.  Here, it detects that the `b.txt` files are identical.

You may use `fdupes` to delete duplicates:

```
$ fdupes --delete A B
[1] A/b.txt
[2] B/b.txt

Set 1 of 1, preserve files [1 - 2, all]: 1

   [+] A/b.txt
   [-] B/b.txt
```

It interactively asks which file to keep (or to keep both). I wrote `1` so the `A/b.txt` file was kept while `B/b.txt` was deleted.

See the manual for `fdupes` (`man fdupes`).  If it's not installed on your system, then use a package manager to install it.  It can also be made to automatically delete files without interactive prompting, but care must be taken when running it in this way. Always make a backup of your data before running a command that may delete files.

Note that `fdupes` will always keep at least one of the duplicates. If you want to delete all duplicates, then you may be interested in this patched version of `fdupes` mentioned in an answer to similar question over at SuperUser: https://superuser.com/a/947770/96962 (I have not tested this).

---

The reason I suggest using `fdupes` rather than parsing the log file that you have is that filenames embedded in a text document are difficult to parse correctly.  It may not *always* be difficult (and is this particular example, it would be easy), but note that Unix allows for both spaces and newlines in the names of files and directories. It is *technically* possible to have a directory called

```
a.txt
Same: A=
```

with a newline embedded in the name.

Comment: I did use fdupes. And also tried it's delete feature. But I want to delete both files. And have used fdupes, modified with an option none! to preserve none of them. Can't find it now.

Comment: @PJ547 You're thinking of this SuperUser answer: https://superuser.com/a/947770/96962

Comment: Yes, this is the one. Thank you @Kusalananda

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'[:]' '/Same:/{print $0}' logfile | xargs -n1 | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | xargs rm -rf
```

`awk` looks for the line in the log file that contains the keyword "Same:", then `xargs` organize the variables and paths (i.e. A=***) one per line, after then `awk` captures the absolute path. In the final step, `xargs` calls for `rm` to delete the paths.

You should be aware that when `xargs` calls for `rm` to delete the paths, this will delete files definitely. The flag `-I` can be added to `rm` to remind the user to confirm deletion.

[rm man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html)

-I   prompt once before removing more than three files, or
                          when removing recursively; less intrusive than -i,
                          while still giving protection against most mistakes

or with `grep`

```
grep "Same:" logfile | grep -oP '/[^ ]*' | xargs rm -rf
```

The first `grep` finds the line that contain the keyword `Same`.

The second `grep` fillers the logfile to get rid of everything except the paths relevant to the keyword. Finally, `xargs` calls for `rm` to delete the paths.

Comment: This would fail for files containing `:` or `=` in their names.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to answer a question with those caveats, as long as they are actually mentioned. Having `:` and `=` in filenames is unusual (`:` is often part of individual messages in maildir mailboxes though), and it's even more unusual to have newlines in filenames. Spaces are fairly common though, for example on standard macOS systems, and I've never worked out what `xargs` do with space-delimited data (I tend to not use `xargs`).

Comment: Calling `rm -rf` on the output of a script that essentially reformats an input file seems dangerous. In fact, this script is vulnerable to path traversal attacks: if a string given as a filename  looks like `/home/username` for example, this could delete your home directory without any safety check or confirmation. I wouldn't feel safe running this command, even if I had written the input file myself. You can always make mistakes.

Comment: The first approach didn't do anything. However, the second one, gave me unrecognized option -- P. After looking on the web. Found it works but only before 10.x something. Still, thanks for this.

Comment: @PJ547 strange why first command did not do anything? I just run the command and i used paths similar to yours. What is your system? Did you get any error message?

Comment: I am on Android, BTW. Using on Termux.

Answer (score 2):

Do you REALLY want to delete all identical files, or just n-1 and keep one copy? Then, why not

```
awk  '/Same:/ {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {split ($i, T, "="); print "rm", T[2]}}' log 
rm /sdcard/A/b.txt
rm /sdcard/B/b.txt
```

and pipe into `sh` when happy with the result.
If you want too keep one copy, start the loop from `i=3`.

Or, a different approach without `awk`:

```
echo rm $(md5sum path/to/files* | sort | uniq -Dw33 | cut -d" " -f3-)
rm file2 file4
```

Remove the `echo` if happy with the result. Should files have spaces in their names, additional steps needed to be taken.

Comment: Impressive. The first approach works perfectly. Can save it to .sh by adding "> a.sh" at the end. Thanks a lot. Also I wanted to know, how can I use the first approach, for fdupes output where the Same: isn't in the output.

Comment: You don't need to save it to a script file - you can either just pipe it `| sh`, or source it like `. <(awk...)` if your shell provides "process substitution". I don't have any experience with `fdupes`, so I just guess: use `rm $(fdupes...)`, if you don't want to use `fdupes`'s `delete` feature.

Comment: I will try. Yes, totally forgot about the pipe function. Doing this after a long time.